# sending state as a prop inside react <Route component={COMPONENT_NAME}>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
        <Switch >
        <Route path="/updateSummary" component={UpdateSummary} />
        <Route path="/updateEffort" component={UpdateEffort} />
        </Switch>
```

I have to  send state of parent component as a prop to UpdateSummary. i tried sending like below,

```
        <Switch >
        <Route path="/updateSummary" component={UpdateSummary 
        {...this.props}} />
        <Route path="/updateEffort" component={UpdateEffort} />
        </Switch>
```

I am getting error as below

```
ERROR in ./component/ts/edit.tsx
[tsl] ERROR in D:\DR\component\ts\edit.tsx(99,67)
  TS1005: '}' expected.

ERROR in ./component/ts/edit.tsx
[tsl] ERROR in D:\DR\component\ts\edit.tsx(99,82)
  TS1003: Identifier expected.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the duplicate,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass the props inside of the component attribute, instead do so like this:

```
<Switch >
    <Route path="/updateSummary" component={UpdateSummary} {...this.props} />
    <Route path="/updateEffort" component={UpdateEffort} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: can i write like this...                                                                           
 <Route path="/updateSummary" component={UpdateSummery} data=
       {...this.props}/>

Comment: I think if you right it that way, you will have to access all props thru the data object. But it should work